# Apache Beam Cloud Dataflow Streaming Stuck Side Input

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm currently building PoC Apache Beam pipeline in GCP Dataflow. In this case, I want to create streaming pipeline with main input from PubSub and side input from BigQuery and store processed data back to BigQuery.

Side pipeline code

```py
side_pipeline = (
    p
    | "periodic" >> PeriodicImpulse(fire_interval=3600, apply_windowing=True)
    | "map to read request" >>
        beam.Map(lambda x:beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQueryRequest(table=side_table))
    | beam.io.ReadAllFromBigQuery()
)
```

Function with side input code

```py
def enrich_payload(payload, equipments):
    id = payload["id"]
    for equipment in equipments:
        if id == equipment["id"]:
            payload["type"] = equipment["type"]
            payload["brand"] = equipment["brand"]
            payload["year"] = equipment["year"]

            break

    return payload
```

Main pipeline code

```py
main_pipeline = (
    p
    | "read" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic="projects/my-project/topics/topiq")
    | "bytes to dict" >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x.decode("utf-8")))
    | "transform" >> beam.Map(transform_function)
    | "timestamping" >> beam.Map(lambda src: window.TimestampedValue(
        src,
        dt.datetime.fromisoformat(src["timestamp"]).timestamp()
    ))
    | "windowing" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(30))
)

final_pipeline = (
    main_pipeline
    | "enrich data" >> beam.Map(enrich_payload, equipments=beam.pvalue.AsIter(side_pipeline))
    | "store" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(bq_table)
)

result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

After deploy it to Dataflow, everything looks fine and no error. But then I noticed that `enrich data` step has two nodes instead of one.

[image: Dataflow Graph]

And also, the side input stuck as you can see it has `Elements Added` with 21 counts in Input Collections and `-` value in `Elements Added` in Output Collections.
[image: Enrich data stuck]

You can find the full pipeline code [here](https://github.com/fahmiduldul/gcp-data-engineering/blob/main/src/dataflow/iot-pipeline.py)

I already follow all instruction in these documentations:

- https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/
- https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.35.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html

Yet still found this error. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide the full python pipeline code ? so I can reproduce it easily.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva Hi, I already added link to my full code, Thank you for your help!

Comment: I expend a time  on it but it still not writing on the last stage, seams something related to the windowing. But, I could get some errors in other parts. 1. fix this step as: `"timestamp" >> beam.Map(lambda src: window.TimestampedValue(
    #    src,src["timestamp"]))`, 2. use a subscription when reading from a topic: `"read" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION)`. Fix those and check if it may help you to advance.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva thank you so much bro! I'll check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you have a working example:

```
mytopic = ""
sql = "SELECT station_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() timestamp FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_stations` LIMIT 10"

def to_bqrequest(e, sql):
    from apache_beam.io import ReadFromBigQueryRequest
    yield ReadFromBigQueryRequest(query=sql)
     

def merge(e, side):
    for i in side:
        yield f"Main {e.decode('utf-8')} Side {i}"

pubsub = p | "Read PubSub topic" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=mytopic)

side_pcol = (p | PeriodicImpulse(fire_interval=300, apply_windowing=False)
               | "ApplyGlobalWindow" >> WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows(),
                                           trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterProcessingTime(5)),
                                           accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
               | "To BQ Request" >> ParDo(to_bqrequest, sql=sql)
               | ReadAllFromBigQuery()
            )

final = (pubsub | "Merge" >> ParDo(merge, side=beam.pvalue.AsList(side_pcol))
                | Map(logging.info)
        )                    
    
p.run()
```

Note this uses a `GlobalWindow` (so that both inputs have the same window). I used a processing time trigger so that the pane contains multiple rows. `5` was chosen arbitrarily, using `1` would work too.

Please note matching the data between side and main inputs is **non deterministic**, and you may see fluctuating values from older fired panes.

In theory, using `FixedWindows` should fix this, but I cannot get the `FixedWindows` to work.

Comment: Thank you so much bro! I'll try it first

Comment: Holee sheet dude, it's working!! thank you so much! But unfortunately, the bounty ended just an hour after I tried your solution.  Do you still really want the bounty? I will give it if you want

Comment: Happy to see it worked! oh, what I pity, I saw the question while I was on holidays and I was waiting to come back to start coding :D no need to create a new bounty, I'm just happy this worked for you

Comment: I think the reason that `FixedWindows` is not working is that it's trigger aggregation by PCollection watermark. When the pipeline start it only receive one element until the next `PeriodicImpulse` send another PColletion (after an hour in my code), hence it doesn't trigger the default trigger, `trigger.AfterWatermark`, since there is no element watermark passed that window. That's why `trigger.AfterProcessingTime` works because it doesn't depend on element watermark.