# Join PubSub data with BigQuery data and then save result into BigQuery using dataflow SDK in python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a problem statement to read the streaming data from pubsub topic (PubSubTopic1) and join the data with Bigquery table (BQTable1) using dataflow and then save the result into new Bigquery table (ResultBQTable)

PubSubTopic1: has ItemID, UnitPrice
BQTable1: has ItemID, ItemName, OfferPrice
ResultBQTable: need to have columns: ItemID, ItemName, UnitPrice, OfferPrice, TotalCost

I am able to create Dataflow job using 'DataFlow SQL Workbench' but this is one time, I can not automate this, hence I want to write python code using apache beam ask and dataflow sdk to automate this so that it can be shared with anyone to implement same thing.

I am new to dataflow hence my approach might be tedious. Better and optimal approaches are all welcome.

Thinking of below things, but do not know how to implement 2nd:

1. I can try to implement windowing to pubsub topic to reach in small batches using time limit.
2. Can we read PubSubTopic1 streaming data in one PColleciton and data from BQTable1 in another PCollection and then join these?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we read PubSubTopic1 streaming data in one PColleciton and data from BQTable1 in another PCollection and then join these

Yes, that's exactly the right way to be thinking about it!

The [Side Input Patterns](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/) page on the Beam docs contains an example of enriching streaming data with a slowly-changing side input. This is a slightly modified version to match your input and output types:

```
from apache_beam.transforms.periodicsequence import PeriodicImpulse
from apache_beam.transforms.window import TimestampedValue
from apache_beam.transforms import window

# from apache_beam.utils.timestamp import MAX_TIMESTAMP
# last_timestamp = MAX_TIMESTAMP to go on indefninitely

# Any user-defined function.
# cross join is used as an example.
def cross_join(left, rights):
  for x in rights:
    yield (left, x)

# Create pipeline.
pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
side_input = (
    pipeline
    | 'PeriodicImpulse' >> PeriodicImpulse(
        first_timestamp, last_timestamp, interval, True)
    | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table='mytable')


main_input = (
    pipeline
    | 'ReadFromPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic='mytopic')
    | 'WindowMpInto' >> beam.WindowInto(
        window.FixedWindows(main_input_windowing_interval)))

result = (
    main_input
    | 'ApplyCrossJoin' >> beam.FlatMap(
        cross_join, rights=beam.pvalue.AsIter(side_input)))

result | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table='my_output_table')
```

`result` here is an windowed, unbounded PCollection and Beam will use streaming inserts to send the data to BigQuery as windows are processed.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your inputs and sharing the supporting code. Let me try this and update here.

Comment: I'm getting error, in line PeriodicImpulse(...) can you help understand what is wrong here?

first_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
last_timestamp = timestamp.MAX_TIMESTAMP
interval = 5

Output:
TypeError: Input to Impulse transform must be a PBegin but found PCollection[[44]: PeriodicImpulse/ApplyWindowing.None]

Comment: here is the code:

side_input = ( pipeline | 'PeriodicImpulse' >> PeriodicImpulse(start_timestamp=datetime.datetime.now().timestamp(), fire_interval=interval, apply_windowing=True) | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=bq_table_stanox) # 100 dict row | "Print" >> beam.Map(print) ) ib.show(side_input)

TypeError: Input to Impulse transform must be a PBegin but found PCollection[[9]: PeriodicImpulse/ApplyWindowing.None]

Comment: Is it possible that you've reassigned `pipeline` to point to a PCollection? As long as `pipeline = beam.Pipeline()` holds then I'd expect your code to be correctly passing PBegin to the PeriodicImpulse transform.

Comment: no, I have used same pipeline object as showed in the above code, assignment is done at the beginning once.
incase of pubsub streaming data in main_input we may need to add  streaming=True in options is it?

Comment: Here is the code:

`from apache_beam.utils.timestamp import MAX_TIMESTAMP

first_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
last_timestamp =  time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime('01/03/2023', "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()) # MAX_TIMESTAMP
interval = 1

pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
side_input = (
    pipeline
    | 'PeriodicImpulse' >> PeriodicImpulse(first_timestamp, last_timestamp, interval, True)
    | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table='<project-name>:<dataset-name>.<table-name>')
)`

Comment: I also get the same error as @user4571139: `TypeError: Input to Impulse transform must be a PBegin but found PCollection[PeriodicImpulse/ApplyWindowing.None]`. Without working code or more information to illuminate how to actually solve this problem, this answer isn't of much use.

Comment: @user4571139 I'd recommend starting at this answer, which has a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70680628/3367614